# Subquery in CASE statement under the WHERE clause (using IN)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query below giving me this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm getting the error from the subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

When you see '5,137' that will be a variable taking its place. 
And `Select val FROM DB01.dbo.f_split('5,137',',')` will return the list of separated values as a result.

Another thing I tried was placing `('5','137')` in place of `(Select val FROM DB01.dbo.f_split('5,137',','))` but I was getting an error on the comma between 5 and 137.

Any ideas? All help is greatly appreciated.

```
select 
    @Total_Orders = sum(a11.ORDER_CNT)
from 
    a11
join 
    a12 on (a11.STORE_ID = a12.STORE_ID)
join 
    a13 on (a12.CLIENT_ID = a13.CLIENT_ID)
join 
    a14 on (a11.ACTIV_DATE_ID = a14.DATE_ID)
join 
    a15 on (a13.PARENT_ID = a15.PARENT_ID)
where 
    a15.PARENT_DESC = 'Vanilla'
    AND a13.CLIENT_ID IN 
    (
    CASE WHEN '5,137'<>'All'
    THEN (Select val FROM DB01.dbo.f_split('5,137',','))
    ELSE (a13.CLIENT_ID)
    END
    )
    AND a14.DATE between CONVERT(char(10), '2015-12-27T00:00:00-05:00',126) and CONVERT(char(10), '2016-01-02T23:59:59-05:00',126)
group by a13.PARENT_ID
```

Comment: You have a number of problems in here. Look at the first condition of your case expression. The string literal '5,137' will never equal the string literal 'All' so there is no chance it can EVER get to any other branch. Then you have a split function which presumably will return multiple rows. That is never going to work like you have it coded. Which value would it use? Why are you providing a hard coded string literal and casting to a varchar which will then be implicitly cast to the datatype of a14.DATE (I sure hope that is a date datatype and not a varchar).

Comment: He mentioned that the string was replacing a variable. I'm guessing that in some cases the variable will equal 'All'

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** (like `a+b`) which can return only **one, atomic value** - you cannot use it to conditionally execute entire blocks of code, nor can you return a result set from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` expressions can only return single scalar values. Separate the two legs and us `OR`:

```
AND ('5,137' = 'All'
    OR a13.CLIENT_ID IN (Select val FROM DB01.dbo.f_split('5,137',',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` does not work like `if` in procedural languages. `CASE` only returns a single value. So you'll have to rewrite your `WHERE` clause along the lines of:

```
WHERE    ('5,137'<>'All'
         AND  a13.CLIENT_ID IN (Select val FROM DB01.dbo.f_split('5,137',',')))
      OR '5,137'='All'
```

I hope I understand correctly that `'5,137'` is a placeholder, which will be filled in with different values. Otherwise it's pointless to compare it to `'All'`

Comment: I didn't think it was very confusing, but for some people it apparently was. Next time perhaps use something like `@x`, then it's obvious it's a variable